# Rails 3.2 - ActiveRecord `where` query with method called on attribute

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

In the console I can query my `Job` table like this: `jobs = Job.where("created_at <= ?", Time.now)`

I want to get jobs that were created this year. If I get an individual job I can use `job.created_at.year` but if I try to use `jobs = Job.where("created_at.year = ?", 2014)` I get the following error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: created_at.year
```

I think I understand that the problem is I'm trying to mix Ruby into a SQL query but I'm not sure how to get around it. Understanding this would help me create much more powerful ActiveRecord queries.

***EDIT*** I found that I can do this using `.map` like so: `Job.all.map { |j| j if j.created_at.year == 2014 }`. Is that the best way to do this if I want to gather a collection of jobs that requires calling a method on an attribute?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Job.where(:created_at => Time.now.beginning_of_year..Time.now.end_of_year)
```

Since, calling `Time.now` could potentially give two different years (before and after midnight on December 31) it would be better to first create a variable for the current time before it is used in a query:

```
current_time = Time.now
Job.where(:created_at => current_time.beginning_of_year..current_time.end_of_year)
```

Comment: Or much more simply using MySQL's native `YEAR()` function: `"YEAR(created_at) = ?"` which will accept `Time.now.year`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski : Oh, interesting. Thanks for your inputs. :)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Except that time and date handling functions tend to be database specific and ActiveRecord is too dumb to cover this portability problem; note the SQLite exception in the question. Of course, trying to achieve database portability through an ORM is generally a waste of time unless you're going to do it the hard way (i.e. yourself) or talk to the database in baby-talk-SQL so this is rarely a real problem.

Comment: @muistooshort : After reading your comment I too feel that how ORM like ActiveRecord have poor/no-implementation of methods to produce complex queries like this. Hell, even `NOT` got introduced in Rails 4 and was wondering what took them so long for making a method to produce such a useful query. ActiveRecord does provide db portability but it's good for making only normal where and join queries, otherwise one has to write raw SQLs to get the job done in real life scenarios, which again kills the benefit of having an ORM in the first place. You've put thoughts very well. Thank you.

Comment: This works for my example case but I'm still wondering about the more general question of how to call methods on attributes within a `.where` query. Another example would be if I need to make time comparisons using a time attribute that is stored as a string. For example, I can't do `Job.where("string_time.to_time > ?", Time.now)`

Comment: @sixty4bit if a date/time column is stored as a string then I'd recommend you to change it in the proper data type. As it will be good for both query and query performance.